# Copy Word content into Excel spreadsheet using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a set of word documents which contains evaluation forms.  I can manually copy and paste these along with their formatting into an excel spreadsheet, but I am interested in automating this using VBA since I have about 400 of these.

How can I open each of these and copy and paste the data into excel while retaining all of the formatting?

Comment: What did you research so far and what did you try (the internet is full of tutorials about such questions)? Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would get the text from clipboard with:

```
Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
myString = DataObj.GetText
```

and then parse that text. You can check out this link https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-string-functions/#Extracting_Part_of_a_String

Answer (score 1):

The first stage is to set a reference to Microsoft Word in the vb editor in Excel. You can then open a word document like this

```
Dim wd as new Word.application
dim doc as word.document
set doc = wd.documents.open("path and mame of word document")
```

'working with a table is like this 'Assume target is a pointer to an excel cell

```
Dim t As Word.Table
Set t = doc.Tables(1)
t.Cell(3, 2).Range.Copy    'this copies the cell at row 3, column 2
target.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

That should get you started